# svn server and svn with xcode?

Tags: xcode, svn

I have 4 iMac in local network and want to make one of these as svn server and other to use svn using Xcode .

What i need to do this ?
How can make iMac as svn server?
How can reach repository throw Xcode ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [SVN server for Mac OSX - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078094/svn-server-for-mac-osx)

or [HowTo Setup a SVN Server Under Mac OS X 10.6 in less than 1 min](http://www.mosacrea.com/howto-setup-a-svn-server-under-mac-os-x-10-6-in-less-than-1-min/)